# Wordpress WooCommerce Checkout Configuration

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, checkout

I am set up to create customer account after checkout with paypal.

I receive the order and customer gets back to thank you page but unless I go in and hit complete the password is not sent to them. Any clue on what I can do ?

All The following are checked. I am running WC 2.4.10 on the latest wordpress.

- Enable registration on the "Checkout" page
- Display returning customer login reminder on the "Checkout" page
- Account Creation
- Account Creation Automatically generate username from customer email
- Automatically generate customer password

Comment: Are you using the PayPal Standard that comes with WooCommerce, or are you using another plugin?

Comment: I am using paypal standard